# foreach with Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`.

For each row of `df1` I need to lookup for a value in `df2`. I have been trying something like this - (below function shows sample operations)

```
def lookup(df2)
    print df2.name

df1.foreach(lookup)
```

`df1.foreach(lookup)` is running but not showing any results.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: can't a left join work ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you need all records from left DF and matching records from right DF

you can use join condition like below

```
df1.join(df2,[<column name>],'left_outer')
```

please post, if you need more help

**what will left_outer join returns**

*LEFT OUTER join contains all rows from both tables that meet the WHERE clause criteria, same as an INNER join result set. In addition, any rows from the left table that do not have a matching row that exists in the right table will also be included in the result set.*

[image]